# How to get scaled down output from given range of numbers

Tags: javascript

I have two numbers MAX = 200, MIN = 110 now a random number, let's say 120 which could only be between these two numbers(MAX & MIN).

Now I want to scale down MAX = 10, MIN = 1 & random number to its corresponding value between new MAX & MIN which in this case is 2. How can I write an optimised JavaScript function that can do that?

Comment: What's the logic for scaling down? Are the new `max` and `min` simply two new numbers, or are they some % of the old ones?

Comment: Here at SO we don't write up code, we help with existing code, so show us what you have done so far. (and if you haven't done anything yet, start with that)

Comment: This is more a mathematical question than it is a coding question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are searching for is a map function.

```js
function rand(MIN, MAX) {
  return MIN + Math.random() * (MAX - MIN);
}

function map(val, prevmin, prevmax, newmin, newmax) {
  var prevrange = prevmax - prevmin;
  var newrange = newmax - newmin;
  return newmin + (val - prevmin) / prevrange * newrange;
}

var x = rand(10, 20);
console.log(x);
x = map(x, 10, 20, 100, 200);
console.log(x);
```

Explanation:

The function takes 5 arguments, the first one is the value you want to map, the second and third define the range the old value is in and the fourth and fifth the range it should be in.

```
var prevrange = prevmax - prevmin;
var newrange = newmax - newmin;
```

calcute the range previously and for the new value.

```
return newmin + (val - prevmin) / prevrange * newrange;
```

The subtraction first: it calculates where the old value is in the absolute previous range.
`/ prevrange` maps this range to 0-1 and `* newrange` back up to the new range.
`newmin +` just transforms it back into a relative range.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```js
function newVal(oldMax, oldMin, newMax, newMin, oldVal) {
  return (newMax - newMin)/(oldMax - oldMin)*(oldVal - oldMin) + newMin;
}
console.log(newVal(200,110,10,1,120));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function scaleToRange(number,MAXinput,MINinput,MAXoutput,MINoutput) {
    return (number-MINinput)/MAXinput*MAXoutput+MINoutput;
}
alert(scaleToRange(120,200,110,10,1))
```

This scales a number proportionally from a range to another. It's as simple as it gets.